How to hide Scaling Options in the default Print UI of .NET MAUI Mac OS?

// Sample code
img?.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var data = NSData.FromStream(img);
var uiimage = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);

var printer = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;

if (printer == null)
{
    // Log Error
}
else
{
    var printInfo = UIPrintInfo.PrintInfo;
    printInfo.OutputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.Photo;
    printer.PrintInfo = printInfo;
    printer.PrintingItem = uiimage;

    var handler = new UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler(async (printInteractionController, completed, error) =>
    {
        if (!completed && error != null)
        {
            // Log error
        }
    });
    printer.Present(true, handler);
}

Expected functionality has been implemented in the Mac Photos application:


AFAIK, that's a setting from deep within the OS. I don't think there's an API that allows third parties to modify the contents of the macOS print dialog. Apple is usually very restrictive with these things.

@Julian Could you please provide more information about those settings? Specifically, which class contains those properties or methods? I'd like to try overriding that class.

There's no public documentation for it, at least I couldn't find any.

This is a native function of the macOS, and the print dialog box content cannot be changed through MAUI
